# Count consecutive columns with the same values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Before I start, here is a link to the sheet example:

[spreadsheet sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpkCoKSp7fA8I312m_kiinvgUv47qevutVluOM3-Jbg/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: h]

Essentially what I want to do is count the number of times the value in `C5` occurs consecutively in its first occurrence.

- In the example on `Sheet1`, the value would be `5` because Hawaii occurs
  5 in a row before changing values.
- In the example on `Sheet2`, the value would be `2` because of Air Force
  occurs 2 in a row before changing values

I count using `Countif()` but I only want the consecutive count for the first instance.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

paste this into **F5** (for example):

```
=MAX(ArrayFormula(IF(C5:C12=A2,
    MMULT(N(ROW(C5:C12)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C5:C12))),N(C5:C12=A2))
    -
    HLOOKUP(0,
      MMULT(N(ROW(C5:C12)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(C5:C12))),N(C5:C12=A2)),
      MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(C5:C12),IF(N(C5:C12<>C4:C11),ROW(C5:C12),),1,TRUE),
            VLOOKUP(ROW(C5:C12),IF(N(C5:C12<>C4:C11),ROW(C5:C12),),1,TRUE),
            0),FALSE),)))
```

or sentence:

```
=A2&" won "&MAX(ArrayFormula(IF(C5:C12=A2,
    MMULT(N(ROW(C5:C12)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C5:C12))),N(C5:C12=A2))
    -
    HLOOKUP(0,
      MMULT(N(ROW(C5:C12)>TRANSPOSE(ROW(C5:C12))),N(C5:C12=A2)),
      MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(C5:C12),IF(N(C5:C12<>C4:C11),ROW(C5:C12),),1,TRUE),
            VLOOKUP(ROW(C5:C12),IF(N(C5:C12<>C4:C11),ROW(C5:C12),),1,TRUE),
            0),FALSE),)))&" times in a row"
```